# Is setting React componentDidMount to async a bad thing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea

I often put `async` in front of the React method `componentDidMount`.  (This allows me to use `await` rather than `.then()` in my asynchronous calls.)

This results in a warning message from my editor - IntelliJ - saying `Incompatible override, should have typed void`.

Should I lose any sleep over this warning?

Comment: I'm using WebStorm and I never encounter this warning before.
I do use await in `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it.

Generally, giving a function a return type of `void` just indicates that callers of the function should not use its return value. If `componentDidMount` observes that convention (and it does), then its return value will never be used, *so it doesn't matter what that return value is*.

That being the case, if you make it `async` then it just starts returning a `Promise` instead of `undefined`. As described above, that difference will be irrelevant to the caller, so you can make the method `async` without issue.